# How can I skip blank lines, when comparing two text files, using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, diff

I used the following code to compare two text files

```
import difflib

with open("D:/Dataset1/data/1/hy/0/Info.txt") as f, open("D:/Dataset1/data/2/hy/0/Info.txt") as g:
    flines= f.readlines()
    glines= g.readlines()
    d = difflib.Differ()
    diff = d.compare(flines, glines)
print("\n".join(diff))
```

and I got this result:

```
- Local Config:   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Uwxa\Kavi

?                                                      ^^^  ^^^

+ Local Config:   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Otgad\Hyikqomi

?                                                      ^^^ + ^^^^^^^
```

any idea how to skip the blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `difflib.Differ.compare` already contains newlines.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> list(difflib.Differ().compare(['1\n', '2\n'], ['1\n', '3\n']))
['  1\n', '- 2\n', '+ 3\n']
>>> print ''.join(difflib.Differ().compare(['1\n', '2\n'], ['1\n', '3\n']))
  1
- 2
+ 3
```

Joining the result with `\n` add additional newlines.

Replace following line:

```
print("\n".join(diff))
```

with (joining with empty string instead of newline):

```
print("".join(diff))
```

Comment: thank you for your help. However, still I have lines thaht starts with "?" and contains blank space like the example of my results above.Do you know how can I avoid that?

Comment: Lines that starts with `?` is there to let you know the columns that are different.

Comment: @user2058811, Try `print(''.join(line for line in diff if not line.startswith('?')))` which use generator expression to filter out `?`-lines.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt do it with linejunk function ofdifflib.ndiff (i think it would have been a better solution). But end up using strip() function that works for me:

```
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines());

for x in diff:

if x.strip() == "+" or x.strip() == "-":
        print("Blank Line... Ignore")
else:
        print("Non Blank");
```